# Why my socket client receive more than one broadcast message?

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm developing an android chatting app with socket io. I have problem while receiving (socket.on) to my socket server, sometimes my app receive more than one broadcast message. I checked my log details on my app and it showed that my app receive more than one broadcast message. I'm confused because i think i did no wrong code. because if my code is wrong that i shouldn't be receiving one message in other case.

This error happens sometimes when there are multiple people active at the same time. for example if there are 5 people who are using their app, then my socket.on receive more than one broadcast message. I've tried contact people who made this server but he said his code are good. i haven't find the answer for days, could you help me? at least give me a clue is this server problem or client problem?

here's how i connect my app to server :
on my main app class

```
 opts.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
 mSocket = IO.socket(AppConstant.SERVER_URL_CHAT,opts)
```

on my activity

```
 mSocket = app.getSocket()
 mSocket?.connect()
```

socket.on how i receive messages:

```
mSocket?.on(AppConstant.ACCEPT_MESSAGE,acceptMessage)
private val acceptMessage = Emitter.Listener { args ->
    val data = args[0] as JSONObject
    Log.d("list obrolan activity", "accept message")

    val message : String
    val author_id : String
    val date : String
    val time : String
    val room_id : String
    val type : String
    val kick : String
    val id : String
    try {
        message = data.getString("message")
        time = data.getString("time")
        author_id = data.getString("author_id")
        date = data.getString("date")
        room_id = data.getString("room_id")
        type = data.getString("type")
        kick = data.getString("kick")
        id = data.getString("id")
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        return@Listener
    }

    var pos = getIndexChat(room_id)
    if(pos != -1)
    {
        if(!id_lastchat.contains(id)) {
            id_lastchat.add(id)
            Log.d("list obrolan activity", " room id " + room_id)


            var item = mChats[pos]
            var unread = room_list[pos]

            room_list.removeAt(pos)
            mChats.removeAt(pos)

            Log.d("list obrolan activity", " posisi $pos belum di read $unread kick $kick")

            unread += 1
            runOnUiThread {
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos)
            }
            if (kick != session.getId(this@ListOfObrolanActivity).toString()) {
                addChat2(
                    ListChat.TYPE_OLDREQUEST,
                    item.room_id!!,
                    item.id_petani!!,
                    item.nama_petani!!,
                    item.foto_petani!!,
                    item.title!!,
                    item.desc!!,
                    date,
                    time,
                    unread.toString(),
                    type,
                    item.lokasi!!
                )
            }
            Log.d("list obrolan activity", " obrolan " + date)
            Log.d("list obrolan activity", " posisi $pos belum di read $unread + ")
        }
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Is this one to one chat or a group chat?

Comment: As what I understand you are broadcasting the message to all the users not to the specific user. Your server side code need to be modified using one to chat emitter. Also you can do this at android app but that approach is wrong.

Comment: @AnkushBist both of them

Comment: @AnkushBist so the best approach is to fix it from server side?

Comment: yes, its code has to modified from server side. Ask the developer who is writing code at server side to read some blogs about how to send message to specific client only. you will get the solution. Even you can also read the blogs and guide the other developer about this.